# Triple equality condition brings weird result

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2012

I'm writing a simple code to print iteratively a binary tree in post-order but I stumbled upon this weird debugging step:

[image]

The image wasn't photoshopped or modified in any way, the "locals" window shows that both pointers have different values but when comparing them against themselves and against NULL the equality returns true and "Wat??" gets printed out, how come??

Am I missing something?

If I rewrite it as

```
if(pointer1 == NULL && pointer2 == NULL)
    cout << "This won't be printed";
```

it works properly

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The equality comparison operator (`operator ==`) is a **binary** operator that associates to the left. Therefore, your condition:

`pointer1 == pointer2 == NULL`

becomes:

`(pointer1 == pointer2) == NULL`, which becomes either:

`true == NULL` if `(pointer1 == pointer2)`; or

`false == NULL` if `(pointer1 != pointer2)`.

Since `NULL` converts to boolean `false`, this condition evaluates to `true` if and only if `pointer1 != pointer2`.

As you can see, this is very different from:

```
(pointer1 == NULL && pointer2 == NULL)
```

which evaluates to `true` if and only if neither `pointer1` nor `pointer2` are `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

It works like this

the compiler first checks, pointer1 == pointer2, which is false(integer value 0). Now that result, 0, is checked with NULL, which is also zero. Hence it returns true.